# More than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms' (only 8.1) and Cordova

Tags: cordova, gradle, google-play-services

Very weird bug appears in my Cordova project when I updated Cordova and Android SDK (all are in the last versions).

Since the update I got the following error with gradle : Error: more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms'

Cordova plugins have not changed and this was working well before the update.
Removing/adding the Android platform or cleaning it doesn't fix this error.

It seems due to the version 8.1 of com.google.android.gms

I use the cordova-plugin-google-analytics which uses : 
com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:+ (I assume the + means last version?) 
Due to this line and with the update the project don't build anymore
Replacing the + with a value (7.5.0, etc for example) works well

Does 8.x has a breaking change?

I saw this post too: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=187464

For now I will force a value but if you have a better solution you are welcome

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this with a hook. Its not perfect but works.

In your after_platform_add add this script

```
#!/usr/bin/env node


var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var fork = require('child_process').fork,
    shell = require("shelljs");

var dir = './platforms/android/';

fs.writeFileSync(dir + 'build-extras.gradle', 'configurations { all*.exclude group: \'com.android.support\', module: \'support-v4\'}', 'utf8');
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution, better than mine.

Comment: I wanted to edit (but blocked by the 5 min)
In fact I would like to know what is the cause of this error. 
7.5.0 and 7.8.0 works. 8.1.0 doesn't work
Is it google fault? (with the release of IOS9 and its lot of breaking changes, we are not lucky this month ^^)

Comment: I don't remember exactly, but in cordova 5+, a google library (I think was google play services), includes that library, and analytics plugin too. So in build time, gradle founds duplicates libraries and crashes. This is a fix until analytics plugins updates this error, and removes the library for cordova 5 projects

Comment: Ah, I understand better now.
Maybe, we should notify the owner of analytics plugin?