# Admob error in compilation: more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms'

Tags: android, cordova, build.gradle, cordova-plugins

i'm a web developer and just landed into mobile app developement with jquery mobile. i've included the admob plugin in my app to run ads on it. But i'm getting an error i have no idea off, i search the web and i was told it has something to do with my build.gradle file and i would like someone to help me fix it. this is the error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
> Error: more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms'
You can temporarily disable this error with android.enforceUniquePackageName=false
However, this is temporary and will be enforced in 1.0
```

Gradle build script

```
/* Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
   or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
   distributed with this work for additional information
   regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
   to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
   "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
   with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

   Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
   software distributed under the License is distributed on an
   "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
   KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
   specific language governing permissions and limitations
   under the License.
*/



buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    // Switch the Android Gradle plugin version requirement depending on the
    // installed version of Gradle. This dependency is documented at
    // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/version-compatibility
    // and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-8143
    if (gradle.gradleVersion >= "2.2") {
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
        }
    } else if (gradle.gradleVersion >= "2.1") {
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.14.0+'
        }
    } else {
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.0+'
        }
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android-library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion cdvCompileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion cdvBuildToolsVersion
    publishNonDefault true

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
    }
}
```

i've updated all my sdks and plugins in Android Studio

Comment: Are you using cordova 5?

Comment: yes i'm using cordova 5

Answer (score 1):

I copy my answer from this question:

[More than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms' (only 8.1) and Cordova](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32874223/more-than-one-library-with-package-name-com-google-android-gms-only-8-1-and/32881793#32881793)

I have solved this with a hook. Its not perfect but works.

In your after_platform_add add this script

```
#!/usr/bin/env node


var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var fork = require('child_process').fork,
    shell = require("shelljs");

var dir = './platforms/android/';

fs.writeFileSync(dir + 'build-extras.gradle', 'configurations { all*.exclude group: \'com.android.support\', module: \'support-v4\'}', 'utf8');
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really used to jquery, since you said you're using cordova, have you tried this plugin? https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova. To add it to your project: `cordova plugin add cordova-admob`

To use it:

```
function onDeviceReady() {
  document.removeEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);

  // Set AdMobAds options:
  admob.setOptions({
    publisherId:          "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/BBBBBBBBBB",  // Required
    interstitialAdId:     "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/IIIIIIIIII",  // Optional
    autoShowInterstitial: true                                       // Optional
  });

  // Start showing banners (atomatic when autoShowBanner is set to true)
  admob.createBannerView();

  // Request interstitial (will present automatically when autoShowInterstitial is set to true)
  admob.requestInterstitialAd();
}

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
```